# Lotus Notes - Mail Document - Principal/From,INetFrom, SentTime, ReceivedTime fields

Tags: java, email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a requirement to fetch the SenderName,SenderEmail,ToNames,ToEmails,CCNames,CcEmails from a lotus notes document instance.

**Issue1**
Looking into lotus.domino.Document API I found out the method getItems. When I write the elements to the system.out values for SenderEmail, ToEmails and CcEmails  can be found.

However values for SenderName(a.k.a From), ToNames cannot be derived that easily.

The values seems to be using an common name format. For example check check my system.output below.

```
Principal = "CN=Amaw Scritz/O=fictive"
$MessageID = "<OF0FF3779B.36590F8A-ON80257D15.001DBC47-65257D15.001DC804@LocalDomain>"
INetFrom = "AmawScritz@fictive.com"
Recipients = "CN=Girl1/O=fictive@fictive"
MailOptions = "0"
SaveOptions = "1"   
From = "CN=Amaw Scritz/O=fictive"
AltFrom = "CN=Amaw Scritz/O=fictive"    
SendTo = "CN=Girl1/O=fictive@fictive"
CopyTo = "CN=Girl2/O=fictive@fictive"
BlindCopyTo = ""
InetSendTo = "Girl1@fictive.com"
InetCopyTo = "Girl2@fictive.com"    
$Abstract = "sasdasda"  
$UpdatedBy = "CN=Amaw Scritz/O=fictive" 
Body = "Hello World"
```

The question is how can I get 'Amaw Scritz' from the common name 'CN=Amaw Scritz/O=fictive'. Is there any look up mechanism that can be used. (I would prefer to have a option other than doing a substring of the common name)

**Issue2**
is it possible to retrieve SentTime and ReceivedTime from mail document instance?
I know that there are two methods called getCreated and getLastModified. getCreated can be loosely associated with the SentTime and getLastModified can be loosely associated with ReceivedTime. Are there are other ways to get times for SentTime and ReceivedTime.

**Issue3**
How can one distinguish whether a mail document is a Sent mail or a Received Mail?

Comment: I think you have to write some code for retrieving the "From" part, splitting it by "/", parsing the split parts as key/value pairs  - putting them into a map, and then retrieve the "CN" part from that map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue1**
You can use [`Name`](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/45e2972296684c2e8525704a0041935f?OpenDocument) class.
Here example from this [link](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/600e149cddce2dae8525704a004193c0?OpenDocument):

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

  public void NotesMain() {

    try {
      Session session = getSession();
      AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

      // (Your code goes here) 

      // Create a hierarchical name
      Name nam = session.createName(
        "CN=John B Goode/OU=Sales/OU=East/O=Acme/C=US");

      // Returns:
      // John B Goode
      // John B Goode/Sales/East/Acme/US
      // CN=John B Goode/OU=Sales/OU=East/O=Acme/C=US
      System.out.println(nam.getCommon());
      System.out.println(nam.getAbbreviated());
      System.out.println(nam.getCanonical());

    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**Issue2**
Use values of `PostedDate` field and `DeliveredDate` field of mail document.
**Issue3**
Check that `$Inbox` folder contains your mail document. Or take a look at [Dave Delay answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25493747/1805640).

Comment: PostedDate is empty and there is not DeliveredDate in the item list

Comment: @user3505441 It seems that your letter is only a draft. Use `getCreated` in this case.

Comment: No! the mails are not drafts. Mail in 'Sent' folder has PostedDate item but no value. Mail in 'Inbox' folder has PostedDate and DeliveredDate items but they are empty. Strange!

Comment: @user3505441 It seems that you have no access to this items.

Comment: I had been using getValueString instead of getDateTimeValue. My bad! Thanks a lot for the quick replies!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @nempoBu4 on Issues 1 and 2.  I disagree with the answer to Issue 3.  A received message can be removed from the inbox, so checking $Inbox doesn't help you distinguish between sent and received messages.

Assuming you have the document open, the best approach is to check two items.  Sent and received messages both have a PostedDate item, but only a received message has a DeliveredDate item.  Incidentally, a draft message has neither PostedDate or DeliveredDate.

Comment: Ah yes that would be a much better way to distinguish the items.